# Mount Blackberry Pearl as USB Mass Storage Device

Tags: 10.10, usb-drive, blackberry

Is there are any possibility to make my **Blackberry Pearl** as USB Mass Storage Device?

When i plug my phone then i check in terminal with`lsusb` command, my phone is detected. But i dont know how to make it as USB Mass Storage Device. I want transfer files easily just like common usb flashdisk.

I found package name *barry* but not as im expected, it just sync my contact and else, but not for transfer file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure your Blackberry to enable the mass-storage device capability.  Note - you can only make the SD card visible to linux.

On your Blackberry go to `Options --> Media Card` and enable Mass Storage.

[source](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Desktop-Software-for-Mac/Can-you-mount-a-Blackberry-Pearl-on-Mac-OS-X-desktop-and-add/m-p/60179)

If this menu option is not available try
`Options --> Advanced Options --> Media Card` and switch `Mass Storage Support` to `On`

[source](http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-8100-series-discussion-pearl/106252-how-activate-mass-storage-device.html)

Then plug in your Blackberry via USB to Ubuntu.  Nautilus (File Manager) should mount the SD card automatically.